# Filter Dynamic keys based on input

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an array and I need to filter out keys based on an input string. Only `OLD_VAL` is static, the rest are dynamic. I tried using the variable but it is not bringing that key

```
let input = VKORG,VTWEG,MATNR;
let arr = [
  {
    VKORG: 1100,
    VTWEG: 10,
    MATNR: 12,
    RATE: 0.01,
    VALUE: 1,
    OLD_VAL: 12,
  },
  {
    VKORG: 2100,
    VTWEG: 99,
    MATNR: 13,
    RATE: 0.11,
    VALUE: 11,
    OLD_VAL: 12,
  },
];
```

Output:

```
[
  {
    VKORG: "1100",
    VTWEG: 10,
    MATNR: "12",
    OLD_VAL: 12,
  },
  {
    VKORG: "2100",
    VTWEG: 99,
    MATNR: "13",
    OLD_VAL: 12,
  },
];
```

**Code tried**

```
let filterResults = results.map(({ OLD_VAL,input }) => ({ OLD_VAL,   input }))
```

Comment: what is this `let input = VKORG,VTWEG,MATNR`? Do you instead have an array of string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `input` is an array of strings, you can use `Object.entries` and create an object at each iteration consisting of the key-value pairs where `keys` are obtained from the `input`.

```js
const input = ['VKORG', 'VTWEG', 'MATNR']
const arr = [{
    VKORG: 1100,
    VTWEG: 10,
    MATNR: 12,
    RATE: 0.01,
    VALUE: 1,
    OLD_VAL: 12,
  },
  {
    VKORG: 2100,
    VTWEG: 99,
    MATNR: 13,
    RATE: 0.11,
    VALUE: 11,
    OLD_VAL: 12,
  }
]
const result = arr.map(el => Object.fromEntries(input.map(key => [key, el[key]]).concat([['OLD_VAL', el.OLD_VAL]])));

console.log(result);
```

If the `input` isn't an array of strings but is a string(`'VKORG,VTWEG,MATNR'`) then you can split it and use the above logic.

```js
const input = 'VKORG,VTWEG,MATNR';
const inputArr = input.split(',');
const arr = [{
    VKORG: 1100,
    VTWEG: 10,
    MATNR: 12,
    RATE: 0.01,
    VALUE: 1,
    OLD_VAL: 12,
  },
  {
    VKORG: 2100,
    VTWEG: 99,
    MATNR: 13,
    RATE: 0.11,
    VALUE: 11,
    OLD_VAL: 12,
  }
]

// using a spread operator instead of concat
const result = arr.map(el => Object.fromEntries([
  ...inputArr.map(key => [key, el[key]]), ['OLD_VAL', el.OLD_VAL]
]));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with either way :

Good old for loop

```
const newArr = [];
for(let obj of arr) {
    let newObj = {}
    for(let key of input) {
        console.log(key)
        newObj[key] = obj[key]
    }
    newArr.push(newObj);
}
```

Or using map and reduce methods of the Array interface:

```
arr.map( e => input.reduce((acc, key) => {
      acc[key] = e[key];
      return acc;
},{}))
```

PS: dont forget that object keys are strings so your input variable should be :

```
const input = ['VKORG', 'VTWEG', 'MATNR']
```